# How to find joint friends of users

Tags: orientdb

I have a Users with friends:

```
User {
    "@rid:": "#11:2"
    ...
    friends: ["#61:1", "#61:2", "#61:3"]
}
...


User {
    "@rid:": "#11:3"
    ...
    friends: ["#61:2", "#61:3","#61:4"]
}
```

How i can to find joint friends of users ("#11:2", "#11:3") with osql?

So query should return `"#61:2", "#61:3"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select from User where @rid in (select out() from User where @rid = "#11:2") and @rid in (select out() from User where @rid = "#11:3")
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Okey, it works. But i think query like `select out() from User where @rid = "#11:2"` better replace with `select out() from #11:2`

Comment: I pressed "explain" in studio and i see, that all documents are reads, but it's overhead. Instead of this query i can select friends from both users and find joint manually in my application code.